# Authentication and Redirection URL in QGIS

Tags: authentication, redirect, qgis

IN QGIS I want to raster a tif file which is in apache server and authentication is there for accessing that file and also the url which I am typing in QGIS is a redirection url which means that it will redirect to the server where tif file is stored.

If without authentication I am typing redirection url it is rastering tif file but with authentication it is showing unsupported raster data source.

I tried direct url with authentication, it is working fine.
I tried redirection url without authentication, it is working fine.
I tried redirection url with authentication, it is not working , showing unsupported raster data source.